# How to use CASE statement with a declared array

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Within BigQuery I want to declare a list of 5-digit zipcodes and then refer to the list throughout different elements of the rest of the code.

I've tried to do something like:

```
DECLARE monday ARRAY<int>
('98198', '98003', '98023', '98498', 
    '98499', '98402', '98403', '98405', 
    '98406', '98407', '98409', '98421', 
    '98422', '98465', '98466', '98467', 
    '98070', '98418', '98103', '98107', 
    '98117', '98110');

SELECT
  CASE WHEN SUBSTR(o.shipping_address.zip, 0, 5) IN --ARRAY NAMED MONDAY-- THEN 'Monday' END
```

But can't really seem to get it to work correctly.  As it stands now my code works with declaring the same list over and over but I know there's gotta be a way to declare once and then re-use the declaration wherever.

Thanks!

Comment: please provide some example of input and expected output as well as logic you need to implement. see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `unnest()`:

```
case when SUBSTR(o.shipping_address.zip, 1, 5) in (select mon from unnest(monday) mon)
```

Note that `substr()` starts with `1`.

Of course, if you want your code to work, you should use proper typing:

```
declare monday ARRAY<string>;

set monday = array['98198', '98003', '98023', '98498', 
    '98499', '98402', '98403', '98405', 
    '98406', '98407', '98409', '98421', 
    '98422', '98465', '98466', '98467', 
    '98070', '98418', '98103', '98107', 
    '98117', '98110'];
    
select *
from unnest(monday) mon;
```

Answer (score 0):

Before providing a query I have some considerations about your code. First, you specified a ***ARRAY*** and passed a *tuple* of **STRINGS**. Second, I assumed you want to pass a **ARRAY** of **STRINGS** because you use the [SUBSTR()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#substr) built-in method which receives a string. Lastly, it is in my understanding that you will have a static array with the zip codes for *Monday* then it will be used to evaluate each zip code in your table if it belongs to *Monday*.

Having said that, I was able to create a query using [JavaScript UDF in BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#javascript-udf-structure) to perform what you aim. Below is the Query in StandardSQL.

```
DECLARE monday ARRAY<STRING> DEFAULT ['98198', '98003', '98023', '98498', 
                                      '98499', '98402', '98403', '98405', 
                                      '98406', '98407', '98409', '98421', 
                                      '98422', '98465', '98466', '98467', 
                                      '98070', '98418', '98103', '98107', 
                                      '98117', '98110'];
                               
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION check( monday_code ARRAY<STRING> ,x STRING)
RETURNS BOOL
LANGUAGE js AS """
return monday_code.includes(x);
""";
      
#Sample data within WITH      
WITH post_code AS (
SELECT '123456229' as zip_code UNION ALL
SELECT '123456789' as zip_code UNION ALL
SELECT '98198' as zip_code UNION ALL
SELECT '98003' as zip_code UNION ALL
SELECT '98023' as zip_code
)

SELECT substr(zip_code,1,5) as zip_code,
        CASE WHEN check(monday,SUBSTR(zip_code, 1,5)) THEN 'MONDAY'
        ELSE 'Not identified'
        END AS DAY
from post_code
```

And the output,

```
Row zip_code    DAY
1   12345   Not identified
2   12345   Not identified
3   98198   MONDAY
4   98003   MONDAY
5   98023   MONDAY
```

Notice that, I have used the [DECLARE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#declare) method with a *DEFAULT* array specified. Then, within the JavaScript UDF, it received the *monday* array and the row's current value. So, it checks if the value is inside the *monday* array using the [include()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) built-in JS method which returns *TRUE* if the zip code is within the array and *FALSE* otherwise. Finally, in the last *SELECT* statement, [CASE WHEN](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conditional_expressions#case_expr) is used in order to specify ***MONDAY*** if **True**, meaning that the array contains the passed value.